# Outlook footer + HTML + CSS - how to do it so it would work?

Tags: html, css, fonts, outlook, width

I have a big problem with creating a HTML footer for my dad's firm. They are using OE and Outlook 10. I've working on the code for very long, but still I have some problems. Can I use external font? How should I make it working? How about positioning it with width: X% ?

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

But it doesn't...

Here's the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>www.k#$#$#$#$#$#$#$.com</title>
<style>

@font-face {
    font-family: times_Sans_Serif;
    src: url('http://a#$#$#$#$#$#$#$.pl/tem/TIMESS_.ttf');
}

p, a, span {
    font-family: times_Sans_Serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}


.header {
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#6d5759;
}

.section li{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0% 3%;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

.section p{
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    color:#6d5759;
}



.section a{
    color: #6d5759;
}

#logo {
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: right;

}

.footer {
    clear:both;
    font-size:11px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    background-color:#6d5759;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px;
}

.footer a{
    color:#FFF;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="header"></div>

    <ul class="section">

        <li id="osoba">
               <p>
<a href="http://k#$#$#$#$#$#$#$.com/o-nas" target="_blank">Marcjusz K#$#$#$#$#$#$#$</a><br>
                +48 500 000 000<br>
                marcjusz@k#$#$#$#$#$#$#$.com
                </p>
        </li>

        <li id="logo">
            <a href="http://k#$#$#$#$#$#$#$.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://#$#$#$#$#$#$#$.pl/tem/image001.png"></a>
        </li>


    </ul>

    <div class="footer">
        <span> K#$#$#$#$#$#$#$ Ubezpieczenia Sp.J. &nbsp;|&nbsp; 31-475 Kraków ul. STREET1 &nbsp;|&nbsp; 32-700 Bochnia ul. STREET2 &nbsp;|&nbsp; 32-800 Brzesko ul. STREET 3 &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="http://k#$#$#$#$#$#$#$.com/" target="_blank">www.kr#$#$#$#$#$#$#$.com</a></span>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me with that? I would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Style sheets are NOT supported by most mail clients. Some inline styles are allowed. Positioning is generally NOT supported to prevent emails from escaping their containers - imagine an email trying to spoof a Gmail menu or something like that.

In general:

- use tables for layout
- use inline styles

For a good guild to what is supported, see:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Ok! I saw that page before, but I didn't know that it's also for inline styling only/mostly. Thank you for help - I will try it once again. Naive I was, trying it that way. :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, HTML emails are a universe of their own. It's like coding for 1999 all over again.

Answer (score 1):

emails are weird in that you almost need to use html from 10 years ago to make it work properly.  A lot of clients strip out most of the things in the head (including the actual body tag).  This includes gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc.  They keep only certain things.  Some keep the styles, but not all.

I suggest you move your styles away from the head and inline them inside the tags using the style="" property and use tables (think back to the 90s)

so you might have something like this:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
  <td id="osoba" style="">..Osoba...<td>
  <td id="logo" style="">..logo..</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="footer" style="">...footer...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

note: I put the id's there for clarification purposes but since we stripped out your id's, they are not necessary.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for help - I will try it once again. Naive I was, trying it that way. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've done it! It looks as I wanted. ;) It was kind of mental pain for me to make layout using tables, but it works! ;P Thanks for help!

Here is the code for anybody who has similar problems:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>www.#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#.com</title>


</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="width:100%; height:5px; background-color:#818285"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="color: #818285;" align="center">   

        <td width="20%"></td>
        <td align="right" width="24%">
                <div style="text-align:left; width:180px; right:0%; color:#818285;">

                <a style="color:#818285; text-decoration:none;" href="http://k#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#.com/o-nas" target="_blank">Marcjusz K#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#</a><br>
                +48 500 000 000<br>
                <a style="color:#818285; text-decoration:none;" href="mailto:marcjusz@k#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#.com">marcjusz@k#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#.com</a>
                </div>

        </td>    

        <td align="center" width="4%" style="font-size:2em; color:#818285;"></td>

        <td align="left" width="52%">
            <a style="color:#818285; text-decoration:none;" href="http://k#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#¤#.pl/tem/logo-poziom300.jpg"></a>
        </td>

    </tr>


    <tr><td colspan="4" style="font-size:11px; background-color:#818285; color:#FFF;    text-align:center; padding: 5px; ">
        <span> K#$#$#$#$#$#$#$# Ubezpieczenia Sp.J. &nbsp;|&nbsp; 31-475 Kraków ul. STREET 6a &nbsp;|&nbsp; 32-700 Bochnia ul. STREET 14 &nbsp;|&nbsp; 32-800 Brzesko ul. STREET 3 &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a style="color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;" href="http://k#$#$#$#$#$#$#$#$#.com/" target="_blank">www.k#$#$#$#$#$#$#$#.com</a></span>
    </td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```